# Eclipse 3.7 RCP Application with multiple plugins

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-pde

What is the right way to make an RCP application that is “ready for plugins”?  I have struggled to do this basic concept and am trying to accomplish this in Eclipse 3.7 (latest 3.x version).

**Step 1**

I would like to explore this by using 3 eclipse plugin projects:
•   HelloWorldRCP
•   HelloWorldPluginA
•   HelloWorldPluginB

Would it make sense to make HelloWorldRCP with all the common things such as a menu-bar with an Edit menu including cut, copy and paste menu items?  The HelloWorldPluginA could add an additional menu-item called “Alpha” and HelloWorldPluginB could add yet another menu-item called “Beta”?  However, the cut, copy and paste functionality could still work within Plugin A and B?

**Step 2**

Next, how do I deploy this as a “product”?  I have made a new product configuration and defined the dependencies from the default runtime configuration that was made.  I do notice that there are a lot of dependency jars that are included, but I don’t think I use them.  For example, I don’t use data-binding to my knowledge, but it keeps coming up as a required dependency.

I go to Export | Eclipse Product and an executable environment is created in my desired folder.  However, when I copy this to another machine it seems to keep referencing the original machines Java installation location.  How does one get around this?

I have tried to bundle a jre with the Product Export but nothing is created.  I have also just tried copying my jre6 as a jre folder.  This does seem to work.

Next problem here is the 32/64 bit Java execution environments.  What is advised here?  I have been aiming to build on 32 bit only and then hopefully that will run on 32 or 64bit platforms.  Is this correct?

**Step 3**

I need to web-start this now.  The old way of initiating an Eclipse 3.5 application, using a startup.jar has changed.  I now use the equinox launcher and reference it in the jnlp instead of the startup.jar.  However, I keep getting an exception which seems related to the 32/64 bit equinox win32_64 jar.  I notice that the export writes a folder and not a jar.  I read somewhere that this is a “clever trick” to allow compatibility for both 32 and 64bit runtime environments.

The problem here is that I need a jar and not a folder so that I can sign the jars required and deploy accordingly.

Does anyone have a Java Web-start example for and Eclipse 3.7 RCP application?  Or any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need a lot of time to learn everything you've asked about here.

Here is one of the best places to start... http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html

That site covers a lot of basics.  But you need a little more than basics.

The best example of a working RCP product with some of the features you require can be found at ... http://max-server.myftp.org/trac/mp3m

This guy (Kai) makes all of the source code available via SVN, and he has some very advanced stuff going on in his application.  He also has a good blog with some advanced RCP tips and tricks.  http://www.toedter.com/blog/

Another thing you'll want to investigate is Tycho.  I realize that you didn't mention anything about building your application, but I've found that using Tycho for building has made my most recent foray into Eclipse RCP 100 times better than the other times I've done RCP work.  So, my advice, get to know Tycho.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card

The learning curve of Eclipse RCP is somewhat steep, but I think it's worth the effort.

Good Luck!